# Turning a jQuery checkbox flip effect into a loop

Tags: jquery, html, loops, checkbox

I am trying to loop the following effect: effect where I can check couple check marks, and when I select the "flip" button, the checkmarks at the bottom will appear, corresponding to the top checked boxes. I rather use a `.each(function() {` loop. How can I turn the script code below into a loop? (Below code does work but I am trying to turn it into a loop.) Thank you for your time, and help.

**Original script below:** When the button **flip** is selected, the **opposite** class checkmarks are then selected, corresponding to the not **opposite_checkboxes**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var ID_top
      var ID_btm
      $("#copy").click(function() {
        for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
          ID_top = "#A" + i;
          ID_btm = ID_top + "_flip";
          if ($(ID_top).prop("checked")) {
            $(ID_btm).prop("checked", "checked");
          }
        }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table dir="rtl" class="not_opposite">
  <tr>
    <td class="dot_wrap">
      <label for="A1"><span class="hidden">A-1</span>
             <input type="checkbox" value="A1" name="A1" id="A1" tabindex="1" class="A"> 
             <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
             </label>
    </td>
    <td class="dot_wrap">
      <label for="A4"><span class="hidden">A-4</span>
             <input type="checkbox" value="A4" name="A4" id="A4" tabindex="4" class="A">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
             </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="button_wrapper">
  <button class="inline" id="copy">FLIP</button>
  <button class="inline" id="clear">CLEAR</button>
</div>
<table class="opposite">
  <tr>
    <td class="dot_wrap">
      <label for="A1_flip"><span class="hidden">A-1</span>
             <input disabled="true" type="checkbox" value="A1" name="A1" id="A1_flip"> 
             <span class="flip" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
             </label>
    </td>
    <td class="dot_wrap">
      <label for="A4_flip"><span class="hidden">A-4</span>
             <input disabled="true" type="checkbox" value="A4" name="A4" id="A4_flip">
             <span class="flip" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
             </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I rather use a .each(function() { loop.

You may select all the checkbox elements having the ID starting with the capital letter A and ending without the suffix _flip with:

```
$(':checkbox[id^=A]:not([id$=_flip])')
```

And in order to use an each loop  you can:

```
 $(':checkbox[id^=A]:not([id$=_flip])').each(function(index, element) {
    if (element.checked) {
        $('#' + element.id + '_flip').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#copy").on('click', function (e) {
      $(':checkbox[id^=A]:not([id$=_flip])').each(function(index, element) {
          if (element.checked) {
              $('#' + element.id + '_flip').prop('checked', true);
          }
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table dir="rtl" class="not_opposite">
    <tr>
        <td  class="dot_wrap">
            <label for="A1"><span class="hidden">A-1</span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="A1" name="A1" id="A1" tabindex="1" class="A">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="dot_wrap">
            <label for="A4"><span class="hidden">A-4</span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="A4" name="A4" id="A4" tabindex="4" class="A">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="button_wrapper">
    <button class="inline" id="copy">FLIP</button>
    <button class="inline" id="clear">CLEAR</button>
</div>
<table class="opposite">
    <tr>
        <td class="dot_wrap">
            <label for="A1_flip"><span class="hidden">A-1</span>
                <input disabled="true" type="checkbox" value="A1" name="A1" id="A1_flip">
                <span class="flip" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="dot_wrap">
            <label for="A4_flip"><span class="hidden">A-4</span>
                <input disabled="true" type="checkbox" value="A4" name="A4" id="A4_flip">
                <span class="flip" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks is works well. The script helped a lot. What if I want to add a loop that allows me to separate the checkboxes into a group of 2 and then evaluate each group of two. How can I add that type of effect/code? –

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the ones on the top, and for each checked one, you check the corresponding on the bottom.

For each checkbox element contained within `.not_opposite`, if it's checked, you put it on the checkbox contained within `.opposite`. Else, you take it out. Since prop accepts boolean values, you can use ternary operators to make it quick.

```
var flipCheckbox = function(){
    $('.not_opposite [type=checkbox]').each(function(index){

        // Selecting opposite checkbox
        // With the same selection index as the loop current one
        // Setting prop to true/false according to current loop

        $('.opposite [type=checkbox]').eq(index)
        .prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false); 
    });
};

$('#copy').on('click', flipCheckbox);
```